# Print PDF in server side to default printer

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created web application using ASP.NET CORE 2 and used [DinkToPdf](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf) to create and download the PDF to target directory. It is working really well to create and save PDFs. Now I want to use server side and print the PDF to target printer in the office. I couldn't find any solution to do this. Please help me.

Comment: The trick is defining the default printer... because it's different for every user profile on a machine. So you need to think about what user account runs the asp.net app process, and set the default printer for that profile.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to integrate this functionality into your software?  If so, there are several PDF libraries on the market with printing capabilities, some more reliable and full-featured than others.

If you're looking for a Windows command line utility to print PDFs to a target printer, you may be interested in [PDF2PRINT](https://dev.datalogics.com/pdf2print/), which allows you to do exactly that, as well as set optional parameters like duplex, collation, custom page ranges, number of copies, etc.

For future reference, questions like these should be posted in the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) forum.